# how to add keywords to optimize search for my android application on google play store

Tags: android, search, optimization, google-play

I have a android google app for eg by the name `Mytravel247`, but the problem is users cant find my application on `play store` if they search by follwing input

- My Travel 247
- Mytravel 247
- my travel247
- my travel 24x7
- mytravel 24x7
- mytravel24X7

Request for a solution on above.....thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Wish there was an answer for it. Tricky google play store.